# Font Awesome css sheet contains all squares next to content:

Tags: font-awesome

I have the font-awesome.css file in the proper location in my head and being referenced properly. When I view the CSS file itself, it shows the class name, then content: then a square icon for all classes in the file. Is this normal? I thought it would be content: then like a "/f106" or something.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean

http://prntscr.com/jgmcyt

On my site, all I see are the same boxes where icons should be showing

Comment: Could you pls. show the portion of `<head> where you refer to the .CSS?`(what you're seeing is definitely not normal, but can you open the .css in a text-editor instead of looking at it in the browser, which I asume you did?

Comment: Here is the head section calling for the font-awesome.css file http://prntscr.com/jh3m9p

Here is the code in the font-awesome.css file opened in dreamweaver http://prntscr.com/jh3n2m

Answer (score 0):

Your .css is screwed.I'd recommend to download (directly from the [source](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/)) and re-upload the complete set.
P.S: BTW, welcome to StackOverflow! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. The link is for font-awesome 5. I was using 4.3.  Are the reference codes for icons the same? Also in the css dir on ftp is a font awesome map file. What is that used for?

Comment: The link points to the site for FA4.7 - but there is a large promo-banner on top which you may have to click away. Most of the 4.7-codes are the same, except that the old fa-prefix is replaced by multiple prefixes (fab, fas, far) for various styles & categories.

Comment: I checked with the creators of the template and i downloaded the original font-awesome.css file from the template and it has the same squares throughout the css file also. I contacted theme support and they asked for a page example of the icons not showing. I showed them the page and he inspected it and found font-family:FontAwesome was missing from the element. Once this was placed, the icons appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the theme is using font awesome 4.7, but you are calling it with html meant for font awesome 5. 
In your html, make sure you have "